# Find all the numbers have this property, its double and its triple contain each digit from 1 to 9 exactly once

Tags: code-golf

192 is such a number, together with its double (384) and triple (576) they contain each 1-9 digit exactly once. Find all the numbers have this property.

No input.

Output:

```
192 384 576
219 438 657
273 546 819
327 654 981
```

Comment: The problem with golfing this kind of problems is that they don't need a real program. Just printing `192 219 273 327` would do.

Comment: `192384576*3 = 577153728` which contains some digits twice and others not at all.

Comment: I think you should rephrase to question to something like: *`192` is such a number; together with its double (`384`) and triple (`576`) they contain each `1-9` digit exactly once.*. The current form is a bit misleading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### GolfScript (<strike>31</strike> 30 chars)

```
1246`{[27*1131-..2*\3*]' '*n}/
```

(thanks to [Howard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1490/howard) for 31->30); or for a non-hard-coded approach, <strike>33</strike> 32 (thanks again to Howard) chars:

```
333,{[..2*\3*]' '*}%{.&0-,9>},n*
```

If the output doesn't have to be character-for-character identical to the text in the question (i.e. if that is a sample), we can shorten to 27 chars:

```
[4.)7 9]{[27*84+..2*\3*]}%`
```

Comment: You may save a char and omit the back tick

Comment: And even shorten it to 31: `333,{[..2*\3*n]' '*..&0-,10>*}/`.

Comment: @Howard, my current understanding of the question is that it's a Kolmogorov-complexity one: reproduce the exact string. Your 31-char solution would add trailing spaces to the lines. If we remove the exact string restriction then there are certainly places that savings can be made.

Comment: I didn't read that in the specification - only to somehow have the correct output format. You may be right, but the formulation simply doesn't read *reproduce the exact string* to me.

Comment: Following your argument you must recall one of your first two solutions: one has a trailing newline and one hasn't ;-)

Comment: Your hard-coded version can be one char shorter: *1246`{[27*1131-..2*\3*]' '*n}/*.

Answer (score 6):

### APL (20)

```
192 219 273 327∘.×⍳3
```

Just prints the numbers multiplied by 1, 2, and 3.

### Without hardcoding (25)

```
{∧/1↓⎕D∊⍕k←⍵×⍳3:⎕←k}¨⍳400
```

Comment: I don't know APL... can you take advantage of the fact that 192 and 273 can be rotated 1 to the right to obtain 219 and 327 respectively?

Comment: odd... that holds for all numbers of both sequences

Comment: @boothby: You're thinking like an APL programmer, but unfortunately, in this case that would be longer than just writing them out, especially since the rotation itself isn't constant.

Comment: What do you mean the rotation isn't constant?

Answer (score 2):

#### GolfScript <s>44</s> 39

Here's a program that's slightly shorter than the trivial (just print the numbers) solution:

```rb
333,{4,(;{1$*}%\;.''*$10,0-''*={.p}*;}/
```

(thanks Howard & Peter)

v1:

```rb
333,{3,{)}%{1$*}%\;.''*$9,{)}%''*={p}{;}if}/
```

Online test [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MzMzLHs0LCg7ezEkKn0lXDsuJycqJDEwLDAtJycqPXsucH0qO30v&run=true).

Comment: In your case you can shorten `{p}{;}if` into `{.p}*;`.

Comment: And two others: `3,{)}%` -> `4,0-` and same with `9,{)}%`.

Comment: Or `4,(;`, which would be more useful if the token following were a positive integer.

Comment: Or of course `4,1>` which fulfills the same.

Answer (score 2):

## Python: <s>84</s> <s>77</s> 73 characters

```py
for i in range(328):
 if`set(`i`+`i*2`+`i*3`)-{'0'}`[45:]:print i,i*2,i*3
```

```
192 384 576
219 438 657
273 546 819
327 654 981
```

Comment: That's some fine golfing, my friend.  I do not understand how python parses those backticks...

Comment: @boothby Nobody ever uses them since they were a bad idea in the first place but all they do is call `repr()`. It's the shortest way i could think of to concatenate the numbers

Comment: Oh, backticks are a good idea and quite familiar.  But... the way you've nested them is just evil.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell: 55 characters

```
[(i,2*i,3*i)|i<-[0..333],9==length(nub$show$1002003*i)]
```

Or 65 characters if it is to be compiled and not just interpreted:

```
main=print[(i,2*i,3*i)|i<-[0..333],9==length(nub$show$1002003*i)]
```

Comment: Save 1 by moving the parenthesis to `length(nub$show$1002003*i)`. Also, the use of `$` to apply `print` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby: <s>76</s> <s>65</s> 60 characters

```ruby
(99..999).map{|n|s=[n,2*n,3*n]*" ";s=~/(\d).*\1|0/||puts(s)}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ ruby -e '(99..999).map{|n|s=[n,2*n,3*n]*" ";s=~/(\d).*\1|0/||puts(s)}'
192 384 576
219 438 657
273 546 819
327 654 981
```

Comment: In this case `$_=[n,2*n,3*n]*" "` is much shorter.

Comment: Another one: put the *no-zero* part into the first regex: `/(\d).*\1|0/`.

Answer (score 0):

#### C#, 109 characters

```
String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",a,a*2,a*3).Length ==9 && String.String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",a,a*2,a*3).Distinct()==9;
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf, @ZafarYousafi. Please note that code golf is a challenge of writing the shortest code possible. That means, _here_ we write unindented and almost unreadable code and force the limits of the language syntax to shorten our codes as possible.